# Is there a core resource type without mandatory fields (for coding test cases with extension profiles etc.)

Tags: hl7-fhir

Currently I am using the Basic resource type for coding test cases like this:

```xml
<!-- https://simplifier.net/validate?scope=eRezeptAbrechnungsdaten@current&amp;fhirVersion=R4 -->
<Basic xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <code>
        <coding> 
            <system value="http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/basic-resource-type"/> 
            <code value="study"/> 
        </coding> 
    </code>
    <!-- "http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/ifa/pzn" is 'preferred' ... -->
    <extension url="https://fhir.gkvsv.de/StructureDefinition/GKVSV_EX_ERP_Import_PZN">
        <valueCoding>
            <system value="http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/ifa/pzn" />
            <code value="." />
        </valueCoding>
    </extension>
    <!-- ... but not mandatory -->
    <extension url="https://fhir.gkvsv.de/StructureDefinition/GKVSV_EX_ERP_Import_PZN">
        <valueCoding>
            <system value="http://fhir.de/NamingSystem/arge-ik/iknr"/>
            <code value="." />
        </valueCoding>
    </extension>
</Basic>
```

These are test cases for validating FHIR validators, in case anyone wondered. ;-)

The block for the mandatory Basic.code element detracts a bit from the actual payload. Is there some other resource type that could be used in a similar fashion and which does not have any mandatory fields?

Comment: Small side-note: XML elements must appear in order, so extensions need to be listed prior to the 'code' element.  The instance as shown is non-conformant.

Comment: @Lloyd: you are perfectly right, and the HAPI validator does indeed catch this small problem (among several others). Firely catches none. That's why these test cases are necessary...

Comment: Note to readers: the example given in my post is *bad* as a test case but very neat as a quick check for a validator, since it makes a good validator report half a dozen different issues whereas poor(ish) validators tend to report none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Parameters](https://hl7.org/fhir/parameters.html) resource type has no required top-level fields if you just want to use it for extensions.

Comment: Parameters isn't a resource that can be persisted or queried for though...

Comment: Thanks, Nik! If you are in Europe somewhere then you may have heard the sound of my facepalm - just this week I had to study the structure in detail in connection with some API designs, yet I had completely forgotten about it. The non-persistability mentioned by Lloyd is not an issue for directory trees full of test files (or strings that are embedded in - or generated by - source code).

Comment: I didn't actually realize the spec says you can't persist a Parameters, that's good to know. The Google API doesn't have special cases for most resource types, so I will admit I've used Parameters for unit/integration test cases, even if that isn't technically correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you would want an actual resource type, and not be limited by Parameters, you could look at using [Patient](http://hl7.org/fhir/patient.html). That has no mandatory fields, and can be persisted etc.

Comment: Thanks! This is even better than Nik's Parameter. I wish I could accept two answers or give more than one uptick. One advantage of Patient is that it has several (optional) 'real' fields, which is quite handy for tests involving the ordering of fields or of fields vs. extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Basic.code is to allow tools to disambiguate instances of Basic, given that Basic can be used for *anything*.  Basic.code is the only element required and it allows non-customized implementations to still be able to filter and search Basic instances to a limited extent without needing to support custom search parameters.  In many systems, it determines whether they can accept the Basic resource at all and/or where it gets mapped within their system.

Basic is the only resource that is intended to be created, updated, searched and otherwise handled that is 'generic' and can be used for any purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting explanation of the rationale for `Basic.code` being mandatory. In a certain sense the element also had a non-trivial role to play in my example - it gave the extensions a chance to be in several wrong places at once (i.e. after `Basic.code` instead of before it as well as being on `Basic` instead of `Invoice.lineItem`). ;-)